# How to pass variable from phtml and how to get variable in require js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, phtml, requirejs

How to pass parameter form .phtml to require js file

### Template file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        require(['Namespace_Module/js/custom'], function () {
        });
</script>
```

### JS file

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {

//here need to get parameter

});
```

Comment: if my answer is helpful to you then you can accept as answer. so it will be useful to another user. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In your **phtml** file you can add a parameter as the code below.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
   "*": {
        "Namespace_Modulename/js/myJs": {            
           "customVar": "<?= 'Your parameter'; ?>"
        }
   }
}
</script>
```

In you **js** file add below code.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/url'
], function ($, url) {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {

      var customVar = config.customVar;
        console.log(customVar);
      }
});
```

In above code `customVar` is equal to you need to pass your parameter, you can pass multiple parameters to create a new variable.

I hope it helps!